# How to prevent the handle of a GtkPaned from being moved

Tags: application-development

How can I prevent the handle of a GtkPaned from being moved? For instance, I want to lock it according to the status of a GtkToggleButton.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the the True state of the GtkToggleButton locks the handle of the GtkPaned, this behavior can be achieved by:

1. connecting the GtkPaned to the button-press event
2. returning with the GtkToggleButton state from the handler

Here is a minimalistic example in python using pygtk

```
import gtk

def on_paned_button_press_event(*args):
    return toggle.get_active() # This is step 2.

win = gtk.Window()
win.set_title('Lock/Unlock the GtkPaned handle example')
win.set_size_request(400, 100)

paned = gtk.HPaned()
toggle = gtk.ToggleButton('Toggle me')
toggle.set_size_request(100, -1)
paned.add1(toggle)
paned.add2(gtk.Label('Toggle the button on the left to lock/unlock the handle'))

paned.connect('button-press-event', on_paned_button_press_event) # This is step 1.

win.add(paned)

win.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

win.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

It might still be possible to move the handle with the keyboard, so you'd want to connect to the move-handle signal as well for a complete lock.